# Drupal Commerce Caching Modules

Tags: commerce, caching, performance

I've been trying to improve the speed of my Commerce site with various caching and performance modules. But the general ones recommended don't work or break my site. I can't see anything else out there that answers my question!

**Boost** - I thought this would work on static pages such as About or Contact, but the module doesn't cache anything at all.

**Agrcache** - breaks the JavaScript slideshow on the front page.

**Core Library** - breaks the login page (which is odd!)

I have views cache installed and that's the only one I've got working so far...

Comment: Have u tried entity cache?

Comment: I haven't heard of that one. It looks good - and I discovered there's an entity cache specifically for drupal commerce too, that caches orders, line items, and products. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You are requesting caching recommendations, but you haven't told us what your bottlenecks are, and what the exact numbers are. If you yourself don't know them, then you won't get far with optimizing.

Comment: I'm just looking into this myself and curious as to why Boost was of no use?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

- https://drupal.org/project/commerce_entitycache

It will cache the commerce entities, rather than build them on each request.

While it works ok as is, after the two "Needs review" patches I added to the issue queue:

- https://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_entitycache?categories=All

I'm using it myself without any problems.

As mentioned previously:

- https://drupal.org/project/authcache
- https://drupal.org/project/commerce_authcache

Also work well with Commerce

Answer (score 0):

I've look at entity_cache, then wrote bridge hooks to register the different commerce entities.

http://drupal.org/project/entitycache

I'll need to also write some business logic to expire the cache. I create both a "timed" expire of about 24 hours and a cache on create/update events.

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you need to cache users on Drupal commerce I recommend using

[Commerce Auth Cache](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_authcache)

> **Authcache** provides a way to cache pages for authenticated users, updating parts of the page via AJAX requests for dynamic content. In case of Drupal Commerce, many parts of some pages are unique to the current user. For example, the cart block is unique per user, and thus cannot be cached with the page it's displayed on. With Commerce Authcache, the cart block gets loaded via an AJAX request after the page is first loaded. This means the page loads very fast, and the cart is still relevant to the current user.

And of course

[Auth Cache](https://drupal.org/project/authcache)

> The Authcache module offers page caching for both anonymous users and logged-in authenticated users. This allows Drupal/PHP to only spend 1-2 milliseconds serving pages, greatly reducing server resources.

Please note that enabling authenticated user caching will require modifying how your user-customized content displays on your pages. You should be an experienced Drupal developer if you choose to implement the full functionality of this module.

But if you need to more : 
then I suggest Varnish + Memcached